# Display ONLY names of colums in MySQL from a table

Tags: mysql

```
select FIELD from (show columns FROM users)
```

This seems like it should work, since `show columns` is displaying a table of information about the table, however. I don't really understand why this wouldn't display properly, but regardless this may not be the easiest method to extract this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the column names, types, and other meta-information from the information schema database.  Example:

```
mysql> select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='test' and table_name='t3';
+-------------+
| column_name |
+-------------+
| col1        |
| col2        |
| col3        |
| col4        |
| col5        |
+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 and FWIW all the "SHOW" commands that show metadata are just aliases to information_schema queries in modern versions of MySQL.  Just in case anyone worries that querying information_schema is somehow less efficient than SHOW commands.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I thought I was being clever with my original syntax, but it just didn't work the way I had imagined. This is as clear cut as I could have hoped.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the table information you can use:

```
DESCRIBE users;
```

If you're looking to actually get the data back in a select, you can use the information_schema.columns table:

```
select column_name 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_name="users" 
   and table_schema = database();
```